# Create menus that slide from left Xamarin forms pcl

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms, cross-platform, portable-class-library

the one you see below is the main page where later I include other view.
I'd like to make a menu that slides from left and opens to two-thirds of the screen.
I come from a programming with WPF, and here, I notice that there 's z-index.
I searched the net but could not find great results.
Can anyone recommend me a solution overlaps grids so as to be able to make visible the need to the menu with its menu items.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="Fimap.WebPart.MainWeb">
 <ContentPage.Content>
  <Grid>      
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
      <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
      <RowDefinition Height="1*"></RowDefinition>
      <RowDefinition Height="9*"></RowDefinition>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>    
      <Grid Grid.Row="0" BackgroundColor="#0084CA">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
          <ColumnDefinition Width="1.3*"></ColumnDefinition>
          <ColumnDefinition Width="2*"></ColumnDefinition>
          <ColumnDefinition Width="2*"></ColumnDefinition>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
          <RowDefinition Height="30"></RowDefinition>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Image Aspect="AspectFit" x:Name="menuImageButton" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Source="Images/menu.png"></Image>
      </Grid>

      <Grid Grid.Row="1" BackgroundColor="#fff">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
          <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ScrollView>                   
          <StackLayout VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" x:Name="downContent" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Orientation="Vertical" Spacing="15">
             <!--RELOAD VIEW HERE--> 
          </StackLayout>
        </ScrollView>
      </Grid>
  </Grid>    
 </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

Comment: if you need a slide menu from the left, have you tried the `MasterDetailPage`?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your needs you can look at the master-detail pages as suggested by skar or another alternative would be to look into this plugin:

This plugin was not always free but these days it is.

- http://xam-consulting.com/slideoverkit-xamarin-forms/

I currently use both, a navigation menu on the left (master-detail) and a filter menu on the right(slideoverkit).